# strategy: how to make some Database results disappear

Tags: database

I'm looking for a strategy to make some search results disappear (and the others re-flow) when user filter the search results.

example:

user searches for some items;

10 results appear, with prices:

```
ITEM #1, £9
ITEM #2, £12
ITEM #3, £6
ITEM #4, £4
..etc..
```

then the user clicks on a filter (eg only show results where the price is below £10)

at that point i'd like ITEM #2 to disappear, and the other items to 'reflow'.

How can i achieve this? I'm not looking at some code at this stage, it's more around the overall 'how should it work?' question.

in my mind i think i would have to perform a second query in the database via AJAX, compare that with the results of the first query, and then remove the results that are not present in both lists. It doesn't feel like the right solution though. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just treat them as separate queries. When the user filters the search results, you just need to include the filters/criteria in the subsequent query.